# How to return popped element in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper

I would like to pop one item from the array, and get that element.

Is it possible in mongodb?

I didn't find such information at

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pop/

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. MongoDB does not return any part of the document you previously had using a normal update, that being said it can return the full document, not just that popped element on `findAndModify` ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/ ), you could then filter that element out, either the first or the last.

NB: I should warn that findAndModify is basically like picking out every document in the query and operating on it, that's how it is able to return it so you might see some performance loss on queries that span a large nummber.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB operations return [full documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-document).

Options could be to:

- Use the [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) command and get the popped value of the array program side by processing the returned document. (1 query)
- use [find](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/read/#crud-read-find) to get the document, get the value you want to pop on program side, and send the [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/#crud-update-update). (2 queries)

Comment: The 2nd one is not atomic, hence may make problem n concurrency if I am right

Comment: for options 1, if my understanding is correct, for $pop like operators, there is no way to selectively get the popped element but can be inferred from the old value (by setting new: false)